# Swiper initialization in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

I'm trying to initialize the Swiper library in my React application. It is not swiping correctly.

Initial steps:

```
npm install swiper
```

Added:

```
import Swiper from 'swiper'
```

Wrote this in the render method of my component:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper (".swiper-container", {
  preloadImages: false,
  lazy: true,
  pagination: ".swiper-pagination",
  paginationClickable: true,
  slidesPerView: 1,
  spaceBetween: 10,
  keyboardControl: true,
  a11y: true,
  nextButton: ".swiper-button-next",
  prevButton: ".swiper-button-prev"
});
```

Created a CSS file that includes all the properties from:

> dist/css/swiper.css

```
<div className="swiper-container">
  <div className="swiper-wrapper">

    <div className="swiper-slide">Slide 1
    </div>
    <div className="swiper-slide">Slide 2
    </div>               
    <div className="swiper-slide">Slide 3
    </div>

  </div>
  <div className="swiper-pagination"></div>
  <div className="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div className="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
```

I currently just Slide 1 is showing. And when I click the buttons, nothing moves. The other slides are generating on the right (can see from console), but the swiper is not swiping. Also, if I try an image with lazy load instead of Slide 1, the image is forever stuck on the lazy load spinner.

Just want to know how to fix this.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library, but my guess is that you are initialising it before the necessary elements have been rendered my React. Try moving the code that initializes the swiper to a componentDidMount method.

Comment: You're a legend! Thank you so much. Spot on!!

Comment: Lucky guess  glad I could help!